# Find the peak frequency in Khz of audio file using sox or python for mp3 flac and wav files

Tags: python3, sox

I wanted to batch analyze audio files for peak frequencies  using python or SoX

[image: file.mp3 with constant bit rate]

[image: file.mp3 with variable bit rate]

Above spectrogram are created using sox
I wanted to extract peak frequency
like in image 1: 20Khz

Comment: this really feels more like you're trying to make us do your signal processing for you, not like a question related to Linux/UNIX. Also, as a signal processing person: 20 kHz most definitely is not the peak freqeuncy (however you define that) in image 1.

Comment: find average peak programatticaly

Comment: Define "peak", please. The word has several meanings, and none seem to be the same as what *you* mean. Also, "average peak" is kind of a self-contradiction, too. Also, this is not about Linux/UNIX.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about one of the topics of this site.